# Working half the time to replace 1 space or nothing

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to write a Python 3.6.0 script to find elements in a page. It extracts the line after words that appear in 2 formats : "Element:" Or "Element :" (with a space before the ":").

So I tried to use regular expressions. It works only half the time and I could not figure out what is wrong in my code. Here is the code with an example:

```
import re

TestString = r"""Some text
Year: 2015.12.10
Some other text
"""

ListOfTags = ["Year(?= ?):", "Year(?=\s?):", "Year(?= *):"]

for i in range(0, len(ListOfTags)):
    try:
        TagsFound = re.search(str(ListOfTags[i]) + '(.+?)\n', TestString).group(1)
        print(TransformString('"' + ListOfTags[i] + '"') + " returns: " + TagsFound)
    except AttributeError:
            # TestString not found in the original string (or something else ???)
            TagsFound = ''
            print("No tag found..")
```

(With this code, I could test several expressions at a time)

Here, when the expression is "Year: 2015.12.10" all the regular expressions work and return " 2015.12.10"

But, they don't work when it is "Year :" (with a space before the ":")...

I also tried the expressions "Year( ?):", "Year(\s?):", "Year( *):" , "Year( |:?)( |:?)" but they did not work.

Comment: `Year\s*:`? You should read up on the basics of regex syntax.

Comment: `(?= ):` can't match. It says "the current position is followed by a space, and the next character is also a colon".

Comment: try this `r'Year ?:'` that says that there may be one or no space

Comment: @JurajBezručka Space is not a regex metacharacter, so you shouldn't be escaping it.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot you're right, thank you. I fixed that

Comment: So after working on jonsharpe answer I figured out the exact thing I was looking for was 
    Year\s?:
Thanks everyone !

Comment: @Juraj Bezručka Thanks for your answer it works perfectly fine too !

Comment: @JayD. `\s*` matches any amount of various empty spaces : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp

Answer (score 2):

I think regular expressions may be overkill here (unless you have a good reason for using them).  You could try processing your text line by line.  For each line you could use the partition method on the `str` to split it at the first colon found.

```
for line in TestString.splitlines():
    if ':' in line:
        tag, __, value = line.partition(':')
        #Now see if this is a tag you care about and do something with the value
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution !
What do you mean by overkill ? That it uses too much ressources ?

Comment: I mean it adds complexity where a simpler, more explicit solution will work.  You'll also be able to understand your code when you look at it again next week ;)